# Sum of concurrently changing variable

Tags: database, concurrency, distributed

I want to keep track of a sum of user-controlled variables.
Each user can add/remove/update his/her own variables.
Users should be able to see the sum change after their own update.

As the number of users scales up, the system will be distributed and updates will happen concurrently.
I want to avoid a bottleneck for updating the sum.
What is the best way to keep track of this sum?
Is a exist database that can handle this or do I need implement something myself?

Comment: can you maybe provide more context? - you can store numbers in SQL and run `select sum(num) from numbers` or you can have a middle ware which will communicate via WebSockets with all the clients and send down the new sum, there are just too many possible answers right now

Comment: The total number of of variables can be very large and wont be stored on the same machine. I don't want to run SELECT SUM or some kind of MapReduce with every read request. I think even if I run SUM once every few seconds and cache the result, it will still cost too much.

That is why I want to keep track of a sum that updates when every a users makes a change. I can allow the sum to be a few seconds behind, but no much more.

Answer (score 0):

So generally, if you know by how much each value has changed you know how the sum has changed and you can use these incremental changes to update the sum.

1. In a centralised was you could for instance use any SQL Database which supports triggers and transactions. You'd have a table with all the description of different clients / numbers and their values and another table to cache the sum. The idea is that the trigger would run on update / delete / insert und just update the cached sum. This way it would be much faster for huge amounts of data, but also much more error prone (you can also just re-sum up all the values in the trigger and store it in a cache, and it would work for few thousand values easily)
2. In a decentralised system you can do something similar. Here you can either share all the values between all the clients, or (as this might be too much) just the change. So every client is responsible for some values and on every change he'd share that the total sum has changed by the change. - example: if the user modifies a value from 5 to 3 the client will broadcast -2. you assume an initial state of 0 and just sum up all the numbers from the clients as they come in. The order doesn't matter due to the commutative property of the addition operation. You only need to make sure that everyone will receive the data, but you can achieve this via [reliable multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_multicast).